# Unable to remove Windows Partition on Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, partition

I have a problem with removing the windows partition on bootcamp.

Using `diskutil list`, this was the result:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         184.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                66.2 GB    disk0s3
   4:           Windows Recovery                         543.2 MB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +184.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            119.9 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

I want to know the safest way to remove the Windows Partition because I am really confused on what all of this means.

Answer (score 1):

*There are two ways.*

**Option 1 (recommended):**

Go to Boot Camp Assistant, which is in the `Utilities` folder. Then click continue until you see this window:
[image]

Select "Remove Windows 10 or later version", and click continue. Follow all the steps, and it should remove it.

**Option 2:**

Open up `Disk Utility`, which is in your `Utilities` folder in `Applications`. Then, as shown in the image below, click the top left button and click `Show All Devices`.

[image]

Once you have done that, you should see something like this:
[image]

Click on the `-` sign when the windows partition is selected and click `Delete`.
[image]

After the process finishes, the Windows partition should be removed.